# HTML 5 Websocket using Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: html, websocket, tomcat7

I just dived into Websocket interface. I ran my first sample websocket code in Tomcat 7, it works great.

Is there any other servers to supports websocket with java programmming?

Any other features with HTML 5 & Tomcat 7 otherthan websocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty ([wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/WebSockets)) and Netty ([examples from netty homepage](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/package-summary.html)) support WebSockets

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Atmosphere?
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

Quote from their github page

> The Atmosphere Framework contains client and server side components for building Asynchronous Web Application. The majority of popular frameworks are either supporting Atmosphere or supported natively by the framework. **The Atmosphere Framework supports all majors [Browsers and Servers](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Supported-WebServers-and-Browsers)**...

Here is a nice tutorial/sample app using Jersey/Jetty as server and Jquery on client-side
http://www.ncolomer.net/2012/03/cometwebsocket-introducing-the-atmosphere-framework/

I am try this out right now. Pretty impressive! (Jetty is good enough for me and I haven't tried out other servers with atmosphere; if you want a sample project to bootstrap yours, you can probably start from [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-the-samples))

Comment: I understand that Atmosphere & jwebsocket providing infrastructure to support websocket. But, my question is what are other servers supporting websocket?

Answer (score 1):

Play framework(1.2.5 to latest) also support websocket. [play-1.2.5 Websocket Link](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/asynchronous)